# How to do an import statement in JavaScript in the Unity3d Engine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, unityscript

I'm using JavaScript to code within Unity Engine. To import a class in C# you can simply use `using`. However, I can just define a variable with full name like `var countText : UnityEngine.UI.Text;` I still want to know if there is a way to import the class first then use it.

Answer (score 3):

`using` is for C#. `import` is for JavaScript/UnityScript.

To import `UnityEngine.UI` and cut down on the amount you need to type for your variable declarations:

```js
import UnityEngine.UI;

var countText : Text;
```